# Dropdown list selected value not working with ViewBags

Tags: c#, .net, razor, html-helper, html.dropdownlistfor

I'm using a dropdown list populated from a ViewBag. The model name and the ViewBag names are different and im using a special id for the scenario.

```
@foreach (var address in Model.CustomerAddresses){
 <div id="div_@address.Id">
   @Html.DropDownListFor(model => address.AddressType, ViewBag.AddressTypeList as IEnumerable<SelectListItem>, "Select a Type", new { @class = "form-control", id = "type_" + @address.Id })
 </div>
```

when the modal for the edit option is re-opened, the selected value is not selected in the dropdownlist. The view bag is generated from a enum.

---- Edited -----

this is how the viewbag is generated,

```
SelectList addressTypes = new SelectList(Data.GetAdressType());
ViewBag.AddressTypeList = addressTypes;
```

function,

```
List<string> type = Enum.GetNames(typeof(WebApp.Common.Utils.Meta.Constants.AddressType)).ToList();
type.Sort();
return type;
```

enum,

```
public enum AddressType
    {
        Permanent = 1,
        Residence = 2,
        Office = 3,
        Other = 5
    }
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you post how the ViewBag is getting populated?

Comment: @BviLLe_Kid I have edited the question with the functions

Comment: Check whether viewbag as value when you reopened the modal.

Comment: @PraveenKumar.erakkingal all the data is shown as expected, but the selected attribute is not set to the necessary option

Comment: @PankajaG [SelectList](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.selectlist.selectlist(v=vs.118).aspx#M:System.Web.Mvc.SelectList.) has an overloaded method `SelectList Constructor (IEnumerable, Object)`.. you already have the IEnumerabe with `Data.GetAdressType()`.. now you just have to put an object as the value you want selected... `SelectList addressTypes = new SelectList(Data.GetAdressType(), /*object here*/);`

Comment: @BviLLe_Kid since this is ViewBags are used inside a loop, won't the selected item be the same for all intances?

Comment: @PankajaG Can you post your loop?

Comment: @BviLLe_Kid 
foreach (var address in Model.CustomerAddresses){ it's already in the question

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to cast your list instead of using "as" keyword and IEnumerable interface like this ?

```
(List<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.AddressTypeList
```

Or maybe using another ways, like **SelectList** class...